# N-Queens problem using other pieces using Go

Tags: performance, go, generics, chess, n-queens

I wrote a solution to a problem based on the N-Queens problem which should use more pieces than just queens. Problem is it's very slow, it probably has to do with how I modeled data and my lack of knowledge on how to compare boards without the possibility of extending from an interface `compareTo` as I would do in a language like Java.

This is the algorithm:

```golang
func Solution(board b.Board, pieces []rune, solutions *[]b.Board, testedConfigurations *[]b.Board) *[]b.Board {
    if len(pieces) != 0 {
        for i := 1; i < board.M; i++ {
            for j := 1; j < board.N; j++ {
                c := p.CreatePiece(pieces[0], i, j)
                if b.IsSafe(board, c) {
                    modifiedBoard := b.Place(board, c)
                    if len(pieces) != 1 {
                        if !contains(modifiedBoard, *testedConfigurations) {
                            *testedConfigurations = append(*testedConfigurations, modifiedBoard)
                            Solution(modifiedBoard, pieces[1:], solutions, testedConfigurations)
                        }
                    } else {
                        if !contains(modifiedBoard, *solutions) {
                            *solutions = append(*solutions, modifiedBoard)
                            println("Found Solutions", len(*solutions))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return solutions
}
```

This is how I represent a piece in the board:

```golang
type Piece struct {
    Name rune
    Row  int
    Col  int
}
```

This is how I represent the board

```golang
type Board struct {
    M     int
    N     int
    Board [][]rune
    Used  []primitives.Attacks
}
```

This is the Attacks interface (I use it to check if a piece attacks another):

```golang
type Attacks interface {
    Attacks(piece Attacks) bool
    Row() int
    Col() int
    Name() rune
    ToString() string
}
```

This is what I use to check if a solution is already been used:

```golang
func contains(boardContains b.Board, testedConfigurations []b.Board) bool {
    for _, k := range testedConfigurations {
        if len(k.Used) == len(boardContains.Used) && EqualBoards(k.Board, boardContains.Board, k.M, k.N) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

And this is what I use to check if two boards are equal:

```golang
func EqualBoards(board1 [][]rune, board2 [][]rune, M, N int) bool{
    for i:=1; i< M; i++ {
        for j:=1; j< N; j++ {
            if board1[i][j]!=board2[i][j] {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

[Here's the code](https://github.com/ignaciomosca/ChessChallengeGolang/tree/0a55e5f244f0812d7f4a3448fb6a446efc9a8b80)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review, Is it possible to post more of the code here? There is not enough code here to show the context and usage of this function. It might be considered off-topic to some users of the site, please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: Sure. I think this time I provided enough information.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems to me there are no generics here... If so, I suggest removing the generics tag. Also, the Github link is not working.